# Suddenly getting intermittent error "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse : null"

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google

I've suddenly recently started seeing errors like "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse : null" on Actions On Google/Dialogflow projects that previously worked ok.

Even now, the error seems intermittent, and happens despite the response from my Firebase function (fulfilment webhook) being identical. In other words, sometimes I get the above error, and other times it works, but the response from my Firebase function is identical in both cases.

As an example, here is a response that sometimes, but not always, causes the error I mention above:

> { "status": 200, "headers": { "content-type":
>   "application/json;charset=utf-8" }, "body": { "payload": { "google": {
>   "expectUserResponse": true, "systemIntent": { "intent":
>   "actions.intent.OPTION", "data": { "@type":
>   "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec", "listSelect":
>   { "title": "Please select one option:", "items": [ { "optionInfo": {
>   "key": "Yes", "synonyms": [ [ "Go", "Lets go", "Let's go", "Get
>   started", "Yes", "I am ready", "Start the survey", "Start", "1", "One"
>   ] ] }, "description": " Start a new diary entry", "title": "1. Let's
>   Go" }, { "optionInfo": { "key": "Stop", "synonyms": [ [ "No", "Don't
>   continue", "No thanks", "Stop", "Stop the survey", "2", "Two" ] ] },
>   "description": " Don't make a new diary entry", "title": "1. Stop" } ]
>   } } }, "richResponse": { "items": [ { "simpleResponse": {
>   "textToSpeech": "Hi. It’s
>   nice to have you here and we look forward to discussing the food and
>   drink you give your baby.Let us know each time
>   you give them something to eat or drink.When you
>   are ready to start, say Let’s go.", "displayText":
>   "Hi. \n \nLet us know each time you give them something to eat or
>   drink. \n \nWhen you are ready to start, select Let’s go." } } ] },
>   "userStorage":
>   "{\"data\":{\"userId\":\"bb46f3f9-e522-2da0-7b3c-302a615d28e4\",\"unicomId\":\"danone2\"}}"
>   } } } }

So in the Firebase logs I can see the above being returned in all cases, but sometimes Google Assistant fails, and the Google Cloud logs show the "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse : null" error, and other times, with the identical JSON returned by Firebase, it happily works.

I'm at a slight loss as to where to look further, if anyone has any pointers that'd be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes it is broken for me as well but in a different way: I have 3 different actions used for testing and local development and I cannot enable any of them for testing in the simulator. When I hit "Start testing" I eventually get a 500 response from POSt actions/agents/draft/createlocalizeduserpreview and an error in the dev console.

Comment: Please contact Dialogflow support and provide your project id to debug the issue: https://dialogflow.com/support

Comment: Thanks Leon - yes, I contacted support and sent them the required details, will update this issue once I hear back and know what the cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this issue - turns out this was my fault, and the JSON response was contructed wrongly (the "synonyms" were enclosed in duplicate [[ and ]]). I believe Dialogflow was suddenly flagging this as an error, when previously it was more forgiving.
Anyway - fixing the JSON response has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. In my case, systemIntent in my response json was null and it caused this error. It worked fine before but recently It failed. I hope it helps someone.